# Warning: fileperms(): stat failed for

Tags: php, wordpress

i've one wordpress installation on /lp folder, when i finished the website i moved it to the root, everything works fine except one plugin "Global Gallery" that gave me an error (you can see here http://www.cagliaridinamoacademy.com/gallery/)

At the line 935 of file.php there is this code:

```
    define('FS_CHMOD_FILE', ( fileperms( ABSPATH . 'index.php' ) & 0777 | 0644 ) );
```

How can I fix it?
Thank you

Comment: The issue is probably due to `index.php` and `.htaccess` not being copied corectly

Comment: where you install your wordpress?

Comment: i moved index.php and .htaccess from /lp to / and changed 
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
to
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/lp/wp-blog-header.php' );

on index.php

installation is on /lp

Comment: Copy (NOT MOVE!) the index.php and .htaccess files from the WordPress directory into the root directory of your site (Blog address).

that's the key, my bad

Comment: what does this code exactly do please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to install WordPress in a subdirectory? If so read through this to verify correct installation [install WordPress in a subdirectory](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/)

or, If you meant to install WordPress in the root directory follow the steps [install WordPress in the root directory](https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/):

You will get a reference from [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fileperms-stat-failed/)

Comment: Copy (NOT MOVE!) the index.php and .htaccess files from the WordPress directory into the root directory of your site (Blog address).

that's the key, my bad

Answer (score 3):

The problem usually appears when WordPress is installed in a subfolder. You can solve this by simply installing an empty index.php in the subfolder. This is because the "file.php"  looks for an index.php in the subfolder, but does not exist. Just create a blank index.php.

Font: https://www.soldato.de/wordpress-fehlermeldung-bei-plugin-installation-warning-fileperms/

Answer (score -1):

Either set plugin Path going inside plugin folder or set `WP_DEBUG`to `FALSE` in wp-config.php file

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

Comment: Copy (NOT MOVE!) the index.php and .htaccess files from the WordPress directory into the root directory of your site (Blog address).

that's the key, my bad