# Error when running Windows batch file with PHP

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I've already configure Apache to execute a bat file, while I need to move files from local server to my computer after operations.

When I run the batch manually on Windows command prompt (copy the file to my computer) it works fine, but when I run it in PHP, it doesn't work.

The PHP runs the bat without a problem if the source and the target destination are on local.

Here's the bat command:

```
Copy "\\180.176.114.15\respaldos\proyecto_bboo\error.txt" 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\caet\error.txt"
```

And the PHP code:

```
<?php exec("C:/xampp/htdocs/caet/copi2.bat"); ?>
```

And a screenshot of the expected outcome: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBDlh.jpg)

I am getting this error message from this debug command:

```
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('B:/prueba.txt')), -4);
```

> Warning: fileperms(): stat failed for B:/prueba.txt in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\caet\permisos.php on line 5

Comment: it seems like a permission problem more than a programming problem.

Comment: May I suggest you install the browser addon [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/)? It'll help you write better English so it's easier for us to understand you.

Comment: thanks im going to do!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: fileperms(): stat failed for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45431506/warning-fileperms-stat-failed-for)

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows that the only part of the code running in `cmd.exe` which works without issue is the part you've included in your question as problematic!